# Why are pre-allocated stacks expensive, given 64-bit virtual memory?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, language-design, virtual-memory

As https://without.boats/blog/why-async-rust/ puts it,

> OS threads have a large pre-allocated stack, which increases per-thread memory overhead.

And the article goes on to argue that much of the difficulty and design effort in concurrency in modern programming languages is about avoiding that per-thread memory overhead.

But wait.

All modern servers have virtual memory, so it doesn't need to allocate physical memory for a thread stack, only address space; the minimum overhead is just one page.

All modern servers are 64-bit, so virtual address space is essentially inexhaustible.

Most modern servers run Linux, which is happy to overcommit address space allocation.

Given all this, why is a few megabytes of address space per thread, considered an expense worth trying hard to avoid?

Comment: *Most modern servers run Linux, which is happy to overcommit address space allocation.*  Which is actually a very, *very* **VERY** ***BAD IDEA*** if you require real reliability.  "Ooops, I just started Eclipse on the production server.  Uh oh!  The [out-of-fuel killer](https://lwn.net/Articles/104185/) just assassinated the production database server process!"

Comment: The default stack size on Linux is typically 8 MiB per thread. The thing is modern servers can have as much as 128 cores (See AMD EPYC Bergamo) and 256 hardware threads. This means some applications can need 256 software threads to fully use the machine. This means an aggregated stack size of 2 GiB which is far from being negligible, especially due to thread over-subscription (typically 2x) often due to different parallel APIs cohabiting on the same application.

Comment: That being said, this simple to reduce the limit of the stack size to a more reasonable value here (e.g. 1 to 4 MiB) with `ulimit -s`. One can only set a specific stack size for threads that really need a large stack size (often only the main thread and few other threads). This strategy is used in many games for example so to create many computing pools while using a very small amount of RAM so to use the free RAM for higher-quality resources. Last but not least, servers with many cores often have a lot of RAM too (but not always since high-bandwidth RAM is rather expensive).

Comment: @JérômeRichard But that's not 2 gigabytes of physical RAM (which admittedly would be non-negligible). It's 2 GB of virtual address space. That is utterly negligible!

Comment: You might think that a couple of system calls (one to create a thread, and one to kill it) and a couple of alterations of the process's page tables and a zero-fill page fault or two are "inexpensive," but some applications have legitimate need to continually perform "background" tasks that are considerably less expensive than that.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Sure! Those are real overheads, that in some contexts are important. But that's not the same as the original claim that it is a matter of several megabytes of memory per stack thread.

Comment: @rwallace, I don't see the word, "megabytes," anywhere in the article that you cited. OK, it _does_ say, "_large_ pre-allocated stack." I'm just saying that the article still would make sense even if you omit the word, "large." After all, what does "large" even mean in a world where some programmers work in environments where each individual byte is precious, and some programmers work on systems where they measure by the terabyte. (I've done time in both of those worlds.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow Okay, yeah, that's a reasonable way to look at it.